# Photoshop CS 6: Oblique perspective tile set creation - preserving quality

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform, games, perspective, skew

I am creating texture maps for my oblique perspective RPG...

I am able to create the front aspect fine, but run into issues with the side/45 degree angle texturing.

I don't want to have to redraw the texture each time for the side view, so to be efficient I just transformed and skewed the front texture to be at a 45 degree angle. The problem is, it appears all stretched out:

[image]

How can I skew the front texture to 45 degrees such that the quality is preserved?

Comment: Detailing the software in use would be helpful.

Comment: @Scott sorry about that. Added

Comment: In the example on the right side it kinda looks like you've stretched that 1 original tile to be 2 tiles tall and like 120-130% wider. Distance from one corner to the opposite corner is longer than one side of the square.

Comment: @Joonas this is exactly my question. I want to achieve a 45 degree angling of tiles such that it doesn't appear stretched, but so I don't have to repaint the original front-facing tile

Comment: @Scott Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have stretched the texture by a factor of two vertically when skewing it. Notice that the left side of the skewed parallelogram is two cells tall. This causes a discrepancy in scale between bricks on the front and bricks on the side.

Now for the horizontal direction. Something being viewed from an angle will typically occupy less of the visual field than something being seen edge on. So you can shrink it horizontally by 2 to presence the subjective scale.

Final recommendation: Shrink the skewed tile by a factor of two in both directions.

Answer (score -1):

I think you just have to use the same height instead of trying to scale on the width. Let me know if it helps ?